# How to exclude certain terms for renaming in Android Studio

Tags: android, string, android-studio, refactoring, rename

I use `Alt+Shift+R` for renaming variables in .java class in Android projects using Android Studio which sometimes asks for permissions for refactoring which sometimes includes string used in java class

Suppose I have variable named

```
int mTest
```

Also somewhere in code I have a String as

```
"mTest"
```

Now if I go for Renaming mTest variable using `Alt+Shift+R` it will ask for refactoring permission to DoRefactor or Cancel .

In such case how can I skip the Strings being renamed in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose `Exclude` by right-clicking on the proper line in the `Find` window:

[image: exclude]

---

Not only you can `Exclude` a particular String, you can also `Exclude` all `comments, strings and non-code files`, by right-clicking and clicking `Exclude` on the root line (`Occurrences found in comments, strings and non-code files (X occurrences in Y files)`)

[image: all]

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. During renaming the variable or member, it will display a popup. In this popup

> "Press Shift+F6 to show dialog with more options"

Now if you will press "Shift+F6", a dialog will open for Re-factor-Setting.